# Power function and involution $f(x) = x^a$

Tags: functions, exponentiation, exponential-function

For power functions we have a variable $x$ and a constant $a$; we get that $f(x) = x^a$. Find all involutions for $f(x)$.

I started out with basic functions such as $f_1(x) = f_1^{-1}(x) = x^1$ and $f_2(x) = f_2^{-1}(x) = x^{-1}$. Is that all of them? How could I be sure of that?

Edit 1.

> Problem description: Is there any involutions for power functions? (i.e. $x^a)$ If there is, find all of them.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact problem statement because as written, I think this is a very difficult problem (involutions are quite numerous and bizarre!). My feeling is that the problem statement is more along the lines of asking: for which $a$ is $f$ an involution? If this is the case, I will undelete my answer.

Comment: Added description, and yes; I need to find for which $a$ the power function $f(x) = x^a$ is an involution. The obvious cases are $a = \pm 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track. Here's a hint: you want to show that $f(f(x)) = x$; equivalently,

$$x = f((x^a)) = (x^a)^a = x^{a^2}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so. To be sure though; with my base cases $x^1$ and $x^{-1}$ this means any function who's a product of two such as $x^4$ and $x^{-4}$? Edit 1. Nvm that's not even close. Ugh, I've been sitting with this problem for 4 hours, I think I'm stuck in my own box of thinking. Would be nice with a full solution if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: You have to find for which $a$ $x=x^{a^2}$ **for all $x$**. This is equivalent to solving $1 = x^{a^2-1}$. What happens if you take a logarithm of both sides?

Comment: $\log_x(1) = 2a-1$ right? And any $\log{n}(1)$ is always equal to $0$, so $a=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I had a typographical error before. It should be $a^2-1$ not $2a-1$. Be sure to make that change so that you should have $\log_x(1) = a^2-1$. What is $\log_x(1)$ equal to?